# Why does my Snowflake Table load keep failing?

Tags: load, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, loaddata

Just created a trial Snowflake account, created a simple (17 column) table.

Tried to import csv into it.

Every time I try I get a 'Staging error': "There was an error while trying to stage "[filename]".
Reason: Maximum file size exceeded."

True, the main file I want is 4GB, but I keep cutting it down to smaller sizes (last one is 72mb) and still get the same error.

Yes, of course I could make the file even smaller, but already missing the point of using the system! If I can't load my data, what's the point of the db..?

I'm sure there is something simple and obvious I'm missing, but I don't know what that is.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mention which loading method you're trying to use. Looking at what you're saying I suspect you're trying to import the file via the web interface, and that's only intended for small files (up to 50mb). If you want to import a bigger file (or multiple files) you should go with bulk load using COPY (this can have different scenarios depending on the cloud you use):

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-bulk.html

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it. Yes, I'm using the browser 'Load Table'. Will check out the bulk load now! Thank you.

Comment: I"m sure I'm being really thick, but...from the above link, I need to upload the data to staging via a PUT command, and then I can COPY it into my table. That all makes sense. But where do I put the PUT command? I don't see a 'console', or a place to type code.  Am I meant to be using an SQL development tool, which I have to connect to my Snowflake environment? I know this is all really basic, but I see no info on these first few steps to get setup. Thanks.

Comment: OK - think I've found it! ;)